# XP alternative to "TEXTSTLYE" Aero theme class

Tags: winapi, windows-xp, themes

I'm using the "TEXTSTYLE" class with [OpenThemeData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb759821(VS.85).aspx) in Vista/Win 7 to render text elements with the appropriate emphasis (all values found on the [Parts and States](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773210(VS.85).aspx) documentation):

- TEXT_MAININSTRUCTION for my header text
- TEXT_SECONDARYTEXT for subtitles
- TEXT_HYPERLINKTEXT for links
- TEXT_INSTRUCTION for standard text

This looks great on a machine that supports the themes, but they're not available on XP. What would be an acceptable alternative for XP that still retains the basic "Header/Subheader/Body" visual distinctions?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, your code still has provide fallback for cases, when user has disabled themes specially for your program, or globally on his Windows machine.

So the solution is to just provide the fallback, using the plain old GDI functions. You may derive the font by making it a bit larger or bold or something like that. On XP, this fallback will be used always for classes not available in Luna (the Microsoft-made styles distributed with XP).